# Changing background in Swift SpriteKit score based

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to build a game (Swift Sprite Kit) in which the background of the scene will change immediately after the user has passed a certain number of scores. 
This is not working (in GameScene)

```
func addSwitchBackgrounds() {

         let pointsLable = MLPointsLabel(num: 0)

        if (pointsLable == 30) {

            let backgroundTexture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "Store")
            let backgroundImage =  SKSpriteNode (texture: backgroundTexture,size:view!.frame.size)
            backgroundImage.position = view!.center

        } 
}
```

can anyone help?

Comment: What does not working mena? The more specific you are with your question and supporting data, the more likely you are to get a response. You'll also likely get a much more comprehensive response too.

Comment: I run the game and the background doesn't change, just nothing happens

Comment: Nothing happens????? Something happens, regardless of whether its the game freezing, or crashing. Perhaps you mean that the background doesn't change? You really have to explain things in detail otherwise you are giving us no chance of helping you.

Comment: In my original game, the background is gray. I want that when the user gets 30 points, the background will change and the game won't stop. when I run the game, it works fine, but after I achive 30 points the background stays the same. Is this clearer?

Comment: Uh you are not adding "backgroundImage" to the scene. And you also shouldn't add it in this method. You should have a property called background and add it to the scene when the scene begins. Then change its texture inside this method.

Comment: @ShaniRosen Yes, thats much more like the info you need to provide. It looks like youve now got a solution, when previously this place was deserted. Providing info is the key ingredient when needing help. Once you provide workable info, youll get a lot of help from the SO community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple example should point you to the right way (just copy&paste to see how it works)...

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let backgroundNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")

    var score = 0

    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ArialMT")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //setup scene


        backgroundNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        label.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        label.text = "SCORE : 0"

        self.addChild(backgroundNode)

        self.addChild(label)

    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {


        score++

        if(score == 5){

            self.backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "background_v2")



        }
         label.text = "SCORE : \(score)"

    }


}
```

First, you make a backgroundNode property and then, later on in code you change its texture. You don't have to make constant checks in update method about current score. You can make that check only when score is increased. I am not sure where do you call addSwitchBackgrounds though, but just want you to know, that there is no need to use update: method for this.